# Passing JS object (associative array) via Ajax to PHP not working

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, javascript-objects

**I am trying to pass a JS object (associative array) that I create dynamically to a PHP / MySQLi query.**
- When I write the JS object (`transferData`) to the console it appears as intended (see below).
- When I test the PHP / MySQLi query separately it works too.
- I therefore assume my problem is with the Ajax call that I use to pass the JS object to PHP / MySQLi.

**Can someone tell me how the correct Ajax call should look like here (e.g. using JSON etc.) or what I have to change on the PHP / MySQLi side ?**

**My JS object:**

```
0: {vId: "04567901", rId: "DE-002"}
1: {vId: "04567902", rId: "DE-005"}
2: {vId: "04567903", rId: "DE-007"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**My jQuery / Ajax:**

```
$('#btnConfirm').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'updateIds.php',
        data: {
            transferData: transferData
        },
        success: function(result){
            $('#modalSuccess').modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

**My PHP / mySQLi:**

```
$postData = $_POST; 
$transferData = $_POST['transferData'];

$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
if($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection Error: " . $conn->connect_error);
}   
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE myTable l SET l.rId = ? WHERE l.vId = ?");
foreach($transferData as $vId => $rId) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $rId, $vId);
    $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

**Update:**
My focus is on the Ajax call as I think there is the reason why the data does not reach the PHP page.

Many thanks for any help with this, 
Tom

Comment: Please ask about one problem at a time. If you have problem with php/mysql, then ask about php/mysql. If yo uave a problem with JS/AJAX than ask about this one

Comment: @YourCommonSense: My focus is on the Ajax call as I think there is the reason why the data does not reach the PHP page.

Comment: parse your json in ajax success `var obj = JSON.parse(yourjsonData);` it will give you object that you can use like `obj[0].vid`

Comment: @mohsen: Thanks a lot. I also think the issue is with the Ajax call. Can you post how my Ajax call should look in this case or what exactly I have to change here in jQuery ?

Comment: @keewee279 check this https://jsfiddle.net/1bwkp69v/

Comment: @mohsen: Thanks for this. I don't need the obj in the Ajax success as on HTML / JS side I have everything I need. My problem is that the data I pass through Ajax doesn't reach the PHP page. I am guessing I need another data type or have to format the data differently so that it reaches the PHP page correctly.

Comment: @keewee279  your data should be json and in your php get your data with `file_get_contents("php://input")`

Comment: for more info you can read this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-receive-json-post-with-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just get your data in php like this:

```
$postData = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
$transferData = json_decode($postData, true)['transferData'];
```

Comment: Thank you. So in Ajax do I have to use it like this: data: {
      transferData: JSON.stringify(transferData)
     },
     dataType: 'json',

Comment: no need if your data is json just putt dataType: json

Comment: It doesn't work with this solution. My data is created like this:     for(var i = 0; i < countCheckboxesChecked; i++)  {
     transferData.push({vId: v[i], rId: r[i]});
    }

Comment: its ok just show me the `var_dump($postData)` from my solution

Answer (score 1):

When you use the POST request is better to indicate the data type you're expecting from the server-side use "**dataType**" in your ajax request, and then parse the data to a valid javascript object in your success handler using **JSON.parse()**.

```js
$('#btnConfirm').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'updateIds.php',
        dataType: 'JSON', // I'm expecting a json response
        data: {
            transferData: transferData
        },
        success: function(result){
            // parse json
            const data = JSON.parse(result);

            $('#modalSuccess').modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't need the data in the Ajax success as on HTML / JS side I have everything I need. My problem is that the data I pass through Ajax doesn't reach the PHP page. Just adding the data type doesn't fix it for me.

Comment: The traditional HTTP don't know what is the thing you're passed into via the jquery 
"data", is accept a few content types the default is plain/text, so you must parse your javascript object into a string, there is many ways to do that the common way using JSON.parse() function.